# In aem access control list evaluation, when a user is part of 2 groups one has allow permission and other has deny which will get applied?

Tags: aem

the ACL evaluation rules I found are

- Allow rights have higher precedence than deny rights.
- Group principals are evaluated in order, both within the hierarchy
  and order within a single access control list ie on the same node 
  (CONCURRENT).
- This list is then scanned bottom-up until the first appropriate
  permission to apply to a page is found

  so when a user is part of both group which rule gets applied when deny permission is at bottom of list? the first rule or third rule?

In case of group-hierarchy how is ACL created according to group hierarchy or in order we give the permission to the group-principals?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the sequence of allow/deny rep policy. If the deny is placed after allow the user will not have access. The best practice is to always set a deny for all followed by selective allowed permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence matters a lot!
The one which is at the bottom will be applied. If deny is placed after allow then no access will be provided to that user. Similarly if allow is placed after deny then permission is allowed. AEM best practice is to first deny for all then allow permissions selectively & accordingly.